# Comparing a variable to a linked list's variable

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a program where details are taken by a user for a survey. It contains details of a person with a pps as a unique identifier. When adding a newNode to the list and checking the PPS it does not recognise if the number is the same in any of the nodes. Adding a printf into the loop to show the current pps gives a nullptr exception. I have tried not using **head_ptr replacing with *head_ptr however this gives more errors down in the rest of the code where the node is added to the list.

```
//a new node is created which is filled with info. Some vaidation is done such as PPS number uniqueness and the node is added to the list
//in this function the node is added to the very front of the list. Note: the sorting does not happen here without sorting it would be a list of the most recently enetered items
//a second function will carry out the sort
void addSurvey(struct survey** head_ptr)
{

    int inputPPS,inputAge,inputSmoker, inputDrink, inputExer, inputIncome;
    int scanfBoolean;
    struct survey *temp;
    struct survey *newNode;


    temp = *head_ptr;

    newNode = (struct survey*)malloc(sizeof(struct survey));
    printf("\nPlease enter your PPS number (Number must be unique)\n");
    scanf("%d", &inputPPS);
    while (temp != NULL)
    {

        if (inputPPS == temp->surveyDetails.ppsNo)
        {
            printf("\nPPS you have entered is not unique. \n\n");
            free(newNode); free(temp);
            return;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
        printf("\nChecking list. PPS is %d\n\n", temp->surveyDetails.ppsNo);




    }
    newNode->surveyDetails.ppsNo = inputPPS;
```

Comment: Why are you freeing the memory allocated for the actual node in the list?

Comment: When you do the printf after `temp = temp->next;` temp might be null (it most likely is if the searched for node isn't found).

Answer (score 1):

You are freeing node once you found it

```
free(temp);
```

In this case after you return from this function `addSurvey` the pointer pointed to by `struct survey** head_ptr` points to freed memory and probably you use it incorrectly.

Even worse, when you assign new value to temp and you might have assigned a `NULL` to it, you are not checking this and you try to access pointer to that unknown memory to print integer:

```
temp = temp->next;
printf("\nChecking list. PPS is %d\n\n", temp->surveyDetails.ppsNo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not link your new node (newNode) to the list leaving the list empty. You have to add

temp->next=newNode;

is an appropriate place